# Order the x axis in seaborn for two columns

Tags: python, seaborn

I wanna plot a dataframe with seaborn lineplot, which has the following structure:

```
A  Year Month diff
Der 2019 1    3
Der 2019 2    4
Die 2019 1    1
Die 2019 2    1
```

Right now I am trying:

```
sns.lineplot(x= ['Year', 'Month'], y='diff', hue='A', ci=None, data = df)
plt.show()
```

How can I get a timeline graph starting with 2019 1 and going over the order of the months without having a time column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a new `date` column from the year and month and just set the day to be 1:

```py
from datetime import date
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

df['date'] = df.apply(lambda row: date(row['Year'], row['Month'], 1), axis=1)
ax = sns.lineplot(x='date', y='diff', hue='A', ci=None, data=df)

# To only show x-axis ticks once per month:
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator())
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter("%Y-%m"))
```